# How to acquire the colors assigned randomly to meshes to feed into base color from color ramp?

Tags: mesh, color

I have 125 meshes and I used a object into random socket and plugged it into the color ramp.
But when I am exporting the animation in .glb format the colors aren't exporting.

It was because base color is not assigned individually.
Is there a way I can extract the color codes of every mesh and feed them into the base color of every individual mesh without doing it manually?
[image: project file]